# Can I use where clause twice in a sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to write a query just like this?

```
SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" WHERE a.namesafe = "namesafe"
```

Comment: aha ok. thanks. couldnt try it because i cant connect mysql server right now. thanks for your answer.

Comment: what are you doing ? posting same comment to all doesnt make any sense as far i think .if you get the answer just accept which you find most appropriate as per your need.thats all sir

Comment: I don't understand wht this topic is closed? I was looking for the usage of two where clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your SQL has some mistakes**

1. You are selecting table alias not column.`SELECT a FROM Action a` . May be you are missing a `.*`.
2. Using double quotation `"` instead of single `'`.

May be What you are looking for is this,

```
SELECT a.* FROM Action a WHERE a.name = 'name' AND a.namesafe = 'namesafe'
```

But yes, you can use two *WHERE*. It'll be tricky though.

```
SELECT 
    T.* 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            a.* 
        FROM 
            Action a 
        WHERE 
            a.name = 'name'
    ) AS T 
WHERE 
    T.namesafe = 'namesafe'
```

Comment: Happily you answered this question! I was looking for this solution!
And it's closed accusing as the question is ambiguous, vague incomplete . If so, how did you understand it ? :)))
How I follow it ?

Comment: @IsmailGunes Didn't get your last question? what do you want to follow?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I was making an irony for this closed question that I need the answer. You answered. Thanks. I did my job with +1

Answer (score 3):

no it will throw an error but if you want to use two search criteria you can use this .
,`SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" and a.namesafe = "namesafe"`

Comment: i know but i must try that option and i cant try because i cant connect my sql server right now. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be both use `AND`:

```
SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" AND a.namesafe = "namesafe"
```

If you want to be either use `OR`:

```
SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" OR a.namesafe = "namesafe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write it like this:

```
SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" AND a.namesafe = "namesafe"
```

Comment: i know but i must try that option and i cant try because i cant connect my sql server right now. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `AND`?

```
SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" AND a.namesafe = "namesafe"
```

Comment: i know but i must try that option and i cant try because i cant connect my sql server right now. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mean AND:

```
SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" AND a.namesafe = "namesafe"
```

Comment: i know but i must try that option and i cant try because i cant connect my sql server right now. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

by using `AND` operator, you can join the two condition:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Action a 
WHERE a.name = 'name' AND 
      a.namesafe = 'namesafe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AND Operator

SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.name = "name" AND a.namesafe = "namesafe

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: Don't use w3schools as a reference for anything - see http://w3fools.com as to why